# Using a trait object in a background job (different thread)

Tags: multithreading, rust, locking, traits

I want to have a background worker which uses a trait implementation / object for some time. The background worker owns this object as long as it is used. After the background worker is "destroyed", the object should be free to be used again.

I tried to make all the things with async/await, but it produced some more problems. Therefore, I use plain threads to create kind of a minimal example. First I also used `Box<&dyn mut...>` to pass the object to the background worker, but I think that is not even needed.

My minimal example contains a `MyWriter`-trait which can write string to somewhere. There exists one implementation which writes strings to stdout. A background-worker uses this writer for a background-job. The worker has a start-method to start the job and a stop-method to join it (in my real code I would use a channel to send a stop-info to the worker and joining then).

I'll post the code and then a description with my problems:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a01745c15ba1088acd2e3d287d60e270

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread::{spawn, JoinHandle};

/* Trait + an implementation */

trait MyWriter {
    fn write(&mut self, text: &str);
}

struct StdoutWriter {}

impl StdoutWriter {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

impl MyWriter for StdoutWriter {
    fn write(&mut self, text: &str) {
        println!("{}", text);
    }
}

/* A background job which uses a "MyWriter" */

struct BackgroundJob<'a> {
    writer: Arc<Mutex<&'a dyn MyWriter>>,
    job: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl<'a> BackgroundJob<'a> {
    pub fn new(writer: &'a mut dyn MyWriter) -> Self {
        Self {
            writer: Arc::new(Mutex::new(writer)),
            job: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn start(&mut self) {
        assert!(self.job.is_none());
        let writer = &self.writer;
        self.job = Some(std::thread::spawn(move || {
            // this background job uses "writer"
            let mut my_writer = writer.lock().unwrap();
            my_writer.write("x");
            // do something
            my_writer.write("y");
        }));
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) {
        if let Some(job) = self.job {
            job.join().unwrap();
            self.job = None;
        }
    }
}

/* Using BackgroundJob */

fn main() {
    let mut writer = StdoutWriter::new();
    writer.write("a");
    {
        let mut job = BackgroundJob::new(&mut writer);
        // inside this block, writer is owned by "job"
        job.start();
        job.stop();
    }
    // writer should be usable again
    writer.write("b");
}
```

The desired output on stdout is `a\nx\ny\nz\n`, but the program does not even compile. My main problem is that `(dyn MyWriter + 'a) cannot be shared between threads safely` (compiler error).

How can I implement `Send` / `Sync` for a trait? It does not seem to be possible. Actually, I assumed it should be ok if the object (or a ref.) is inside `Arc<Mutex<...>>`, but that does not seem to be sufficient. Why not?

Maybe someone has an idea how this can be fixed or even more important what exactly is the underlying issue?

Comment: A rule of thumb for Rust beginners: if you've just created a struct that has one or more lifetimes attached to it, it's _probably_ not what you want. Types with lifetimes are extremely useful, but are an advanced concept; for most "normal" usage what you need is ownership. (Lifetimes in function arguments are a different matter - those are fairly basic and used often.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a reference in an `Arc` doesn't work. Since the `Arc` can be kept alive indefinitely simply by cloning it, the reference could easily outlive whatever it was borrowed from, so that can't compile. You need to put an owned object in the `Arc`, such as `Box<dyn MyWriter>`. (Ideally you'd just use `Arc<dyn MyWriter>`, but that would conflict with returning the writer from the `BackgroundJob`, as shown below.)

Since you can't borrow from `writer` in main, you must move it into the `BackgroundJob`. But at this point you've relinquished ownership over `writer`, having moved the value to `BackgroundJob`, so your only option is to have `BackgroundJob` *return* the writer. However, since `BackgroundJob` keeps its writer behind a trait object, it can only give back the `Box<dyn MyWriter>` it stores, not the original `StdoutWriter`.

Here is the version that works that way, retaining type erasure and giving back the type-erased writer:

```
// Trait definition and StdoutWriter implementation unchanged

struct BackgroundJob {
    writer: Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn MyWriter + Send>>>,
    job: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl BackgroundJob {
    pub fn new(writer: Box<dyn MyWriter + Send>) -> Self {
        Self {
            writer: Arc::new(Mutex::new(writer)),
            job: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn start(&mut self) {
        assert!(self.job.is_none());
        let writer = Arc::clone(&self.writer);
        self.job = Some(std::thread::spawn(move || {
            // this background job uses "writer"
            let mut my_writer = writer.lock().unwrap();
            my_writer.write("x");
            // do something
            my_writer.write("y");
        }));
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) {
        if let Some(job) = self.job.take() {
            job.join().unwrap();
        }
    }

    pub fn into_writer(self) -> Box<dyn MyWriter> {
        Arc::try_unwrap(self.writer)
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!())
            .into_inner()
            .unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut writer = StdoutWriter::new();
    writer.write("a");
    let mut writer = {
        let mut job = BackgroundJob::new(Box::new(writer));
        job.start();
        job.stop();
        job.into_writer()
    };
    writer.write("b");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=64b111d249528decf1ff1d6537e03aa4)

A version that gave back the writer of the same type would have to give up on type erasure and be generic over the writer type. Though a bit more complex, its ownership semantics would be very close (at least conceptually) to what you originally envisioned:

```
struct BackgroundJob<W> {
    writer: Arc<Mutex<W>>,
    job: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl<W: MyWriter + Send + 'static> BackgroundJob<W> {
    pub fn new(writer: W) -> Self {
        Self {
            writer: Arc::new(Mutex::new(writer)),
            job: None,
        }
    }

    // start() and stop() are unchanged

    pub fn into_writer(self) -> W {
        Arc::try_unwrap(self.writer)
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!())
            .into_inner()
            .unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut writer = StdoutWriter::new();
    writer.write("a");
    {
        // inside this block, writer is moved into "job"
        let mut job = BackgroundJob::new(writer);
        job.start();
        job.stop();
        // reclaim the writer
        writer = job.into_writer();
    }
    writer.write("b");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1743958e1b980ec532901421b1fa4510)

Comment: Both `Arc` and `Box` are heap allocated, so it makes no sense to have `Arc<Mutex<Box<T>>>`.  Arc's & Mutex's content can be unsized, so you can just have `Arc<dyn Trait>` or `Arc<Mutex<dyn Trait>>`

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I have addressed this in an edit of the answer at the end of the first paragraph. To elaborate, the problem with `Arc<Mutex<dyn Trait>>` is that it doesn't allow returning the `dyn Trait` part, you can return the whole `Arc<Mutex<...>>` or nothing. This is why in your answer the code in `main()` has to keep locking the mutex even after it has been returned from the `BackgroundJob`. (I'm not saying there's anything wrong with that approach, just pointing out the different trade-offs.)

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that you want to pass a reference to the thread. The problem with that approach is that the thread can outlive the referenced object. Obviously this does not happen in your case, but the rust compiler cannot reason about that.

The solution to that problem is to use `Arc<Mutex<dyn MyType>>` instead of `Arc<Mutex<&dyn MyType>>` - no lifetimes - no problems.

The next issue is with `Mutex<T>` - it can be send across threads only if `T` can. So you have to make `T`, in your case `dyn MyType`, implement `Send`. This can be done in two ways:

1. Make `MyType` require `Send` - in that case that trait can be implemented only by `Send` objects:

```rust
trait MyWriter : Send{
    fn write(&mut self, text: &str);
}
```

2. Or use an additional trait bound - in that case your trait is less restrictive, but you must always specify `MyTrait + Send` when you want to send it across threads:

```
Arc<Mutex<dyn MyWriter + Send>>
```

So far so good, but now your `new()` method does not work, because `dyn MyWriter` is not `Sized`. In order to fix that you have to make your method generic:

```
    pub fn new<T: MyWriter + Send>(writer: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            writer: Arc::new(Mutex::new(writer)),
            job: None,
        }
    }
```

or directly pass an `Arc<Mutex<dyn MyWriter + Send>>`:

```
    pub fn new(writer: Arc<Mutex<dyn MyWriter + Send>>) -> Self {
        Self { writer, job: None }
    }
```

Full working code

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread::JoinHandle;

trait MyWriter {
    fn write(&mut self, text: &str);
}

struct StdoutWriter {}

impl StdoutWriter {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

impl MyWriter for StdoutWriter {
    fn write(&mut self, text: &str) {
        println!("{}", text);
    }
}

/* A background job which uses a "MyWriter" */
struct BackgroundJob {
    writer: Arc<Mutex<dyn MyWriter + Send>>,
    job: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl BackgroundJob {
    pub fn new(writer: Arc<Mutex<dyn MyWriter + Send>>) -> Self {
        Self { writer, job: None }
    }

    pub fn start(&mut self) {
        assert!(self.job.is_none());
        let writer = self.writer.clone();
        self.job = Some(std::thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut my_writer = writer.lock().unwrap();
            my_writer.write("x");
            // do something
            my_writer.write("y");
        }));
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) {
        if let Some(job) = self.job.take() {
            job.join().unwrap();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut writer = StdoutWriter::new();
    writer.write("a");

    let writer = Arc::new(Mutex::new(writer));

    {
        let mut job = BackgroundJob::new(writer.clone());
        // inside this block, writer is owned by "job"
        job.start();
        job.stop();
    }
    // you have to acquire the lock in order to use the writer
    writer.lock().unwrap_or_else(|e| e.into_inner()).write("b");
}
```

Comment: Both answers are great and super helpful (including really extended descriptions of the problems in my code). Unfortunately, I can only accept one. I did not know which one I should accept, so I've simply picked the older answer, but both answers are identically good. Sorry for that.